# How to implement the Python "... not in ..." in C++ using lists/arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently learning programming and doing some simple projects using Python and want to try them in C++ and JavaScript aswell.

In this problem, I built a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game in Python and now I want to convert it in C++. The part where I am stuck at is the part when it detecs a tie. I researched but I got nothing. I am pretty sure it's a very beginner mistake but I can't find the solution to it.

How can I implement this from Python:

```
if "-" not in board:
    ...
```

to C++? In my case, `board` is a list/array.

I tried using this variant:

```
int checker = 0;
    while (board[checker] != '\0') {
        if (board[checker] != '-') {
            display(board);
            cout << "The game is a tie!";
            break;
        }
        checker++;
    }
```

But I instantly realised that the moment when there's a different character other than `'-'`, the code is going to break - which is not the correct thing to do. There are two values that differ from `'-'`, they're: `'X'` for `player1` and `'O' - not zero` for `player2`.

I appreciate you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: if (container.end() == container.find("-")) You didn't provide the declaration of the container, so how you implement find may vary.

Comment: The C++ standard library have many [algorithmic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), some which can be used to [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (or "not" find) values in a container.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Sorry for not clarifying that. It's a simple array with characters (char board[]...) - (specifically 9 elements, excluding '\0').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just using `char board[9]`, then you can use `std::find` like the below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char board[9] = {};
    char *const boardEnd = board + 9;

    if ( std::find( board, boardEnd, '-' ) == boardEnd )
        std::cout << "Not found";
    else
        std::cout << "found";

    board[4] = '-';

    if ( std::find( board, boardEnd, '-' ) == boardEnd )
        std::cout << "Not found";
    else
        std::cout << "found";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChrisMM! That solved it and it removed the 'useless' while loop also. I appreciate your help!